# Electron Error: Specified procedure could not be found: node.napi.node

Tags: node.js, windows, installation, electron

I have compiled an electron program and tried to install in some Windows machines.
It's giving me this error

Specified procedure could not be found:  node.napi.node

Any idea what's causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows Version
WIndows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the node.napi.node is part of the prebuilds of the USB module.

/node_modules/usb/prebuilds/win32-x64/node.napi.node

How do you include these prebuilds to the asar when compiling using electron builder?

Thanks!

Comment: WebUSB is only supported in Windows 8.1 or above :(